# Run function on cell in column, based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe full of scientific paper information.

**My Dataframe**:

```
        database    authors                                                  title
0  sciencedirect   [{'surname': 'Sharafaldin', 'first_name': 'Iman'},        An eval...
                    {'surname': 'Lashkari', 'first_name': 'Arash Habibi'}] 
1  sciencedirect   [{'surname': 'Srinivas', 'first_name': 'Jangirala'},      Governmen...
                    {'surname': 'Das', 'first_name': 'Ashok Kumar'}]
2  sciencedirect   [{'surname': 'Bongiovanni', 'first_name': 'Ivano'}]       The last...
3  ieeexplore      [Igor Kotenko, Andrey Chechulin]                          Cyber Attac...
```

As you can see, the authors column contains a list of dictionarys, but **only** where the database is `sciencedirect`. In order to perform some analysis, I need to clean my data. Therefore, my goal is to put the names just into lists like in row 4.

**What i want**:

```
# From:
[{'surname': 'Sharafaldin', 'first_name': 'Iman'}, {'surname': 'Lashkari', 'first_name': 'Arash Habibi'}]

# To:
[Iman Sharafaldin, Arash Habibi Lashkari]
```

**My appraoch** is to createa two masks, one for the database column, extracting only `sciencedirect` papers and the other mask is the whole `authors` column. From these mask, a new dataframe is created, on which column "authors" i run the code shown below. It extracts the author names of each cell and stores them in a list, just as i want it:

```
scidir_mask = df["database"] == 'sciencedirect'
authors_col = df["authors"] is not None
only_scidir = df[authors_col & scidir_mask]

for cell in only_scidir["authors"]:
    # get each list from cell
    cell_list = []
    for dictionary in cell:
        # get the values from dict and reverse into list
        name_as_list = [*dictionary.values()][::-1]
        # make list from first and surname a string
        author = ' '.join(name_as_list)
        cell_list.append(author)
```

So at the end of the above code, the `cell_list` contains the authors names in the way I want.
But I can't get my head around, on how to store these `cell_lists` back into the original dataframe.

---

So, how do I get the authors cell, where the database is `sciencedirect`,perform my little function and store the output of my function back into the cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is create custom function with `f-string`s and apply only to filtered rows:

```
scidir_mask = df["database"] == 'sciencedirect'
f = lambda x: [f"{y['first_name']} {y['surname']}" for y in x]
df.loc[scidir_mask, 'authors'] = df.loc[scidir_mask, 'authors'].apply(f)
print (df)
        database                                    authors        title
0  sciencedirect  [Iman Sharafaldin, Arash Habibi Lashkari]      An eval
1  sciencedirect      [Jangirala Srinivas, Ashok Kumar Das]    Governmen
2  sciencedirect                        [Ivano Bongiovanni]     The last
3     ieeexplore           [Igor Kotenko, Andrey Chechulin]  Cyber Attac
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks for the fast answer.
Could you explain your solution a bit? Like what this f"{}" does and what happens with the df.loc command